# stack operation in recursive fibonacci series

Tags: recursion, stack

What happens in the stack during the recursive function operation?I am having a lot of trouble understanding the branching of the stack during these function calls.Someone breaking it down will really help me

Comment: where is your recursive function? Best way to learn is by debugging the code.

Comment: @SMA it doesn't matter what exactly the recursive function is. Stop encouraging users to post irrelevant details. I bet you're the type to delete your comment and then vote to close the question based on what you've JUST encouraged them to do.

Comment: f(n-1)+f(n-2) is the recursive  function @SMA

Comment: @user234461 Are you encouraging people to post home work without doing any work? Just chill...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a function call is encountered, the program will create a new stack frame, allocating space for local (automatic) variables.

So in this case, to evaluate `f(n-1) + f(n-2)`, the program will first increment the stack pointer to make space for the `f(n-1)` call, and then call the function. Inside that function, it will find another `f(n-1)`, and will evaluate `f((n-1)-1)`, and so on until it reaches the base case. After returning from the base case, it will then evaluate `f((((n-1)-1)...-2)` (the second term in `f(n-1)+f(n-2)` etc.

So for example, the sequence of calls will be

f(4)

f(3)

f(2)

f(1) (base case, return)

f(0) (base case for f(n-2), return to evalutation of f(2))

return from f(2) to f(3), having computed f(1) + f(0)

f(3 - 2 = 1) again from the call to f(3). Return immediately because f(1) is a base case.

f(4 - 2 = 2) from f(4)

f(1) from f(2) (again)

f(0) from f(2) (again)

return from f(2)

return from f(4)

You will have noticed this isn't very efficient.

As @SMA said, look into using a debugger such as `pdb` in Python or `gdb` in C - it will give you a great insight into what happens to the stack.